# Compare a string with another string inside an array

Tags: c++

Good afternoon,

I'm currently working on an assignment with a custom programming environment using a sublanguage of c++ that lacks some of it's features.

I have written this code:

```
char comparameEsto(char voy, char vengo, pueblo sitios1, pueblo sitios2, pueblo sitios3,pueblo sitios4){
    bool  encontradoOrigen;
    bool encontradoDestino;
    char copia;
    for(int i=0; i<13;i++){
        strcpy(copia,sitios1[i]);
    }
}

char comparameEsto(char voy, char vengo, pueblo sitios1, pueblo sitios2, pueblo sitios3,pueblo sitios4){
    bool  encontradoOrigen;
    bool encontradoDestino;
    char copia;
    for(int i=0; i<13;i++){
        strcmp(voy,sitios1[i]);
    }
}
```

It's just an example of the functionality I'm looking for. The thing is, I want to copy the String inside `sitios1` to `copia`, or compare them with `voy` and `vengo`, but it keeps telling me this:

```
invalid conversion from `char' to `char*'
```

I'm not very fluent in C++ (I'm more used to Java), and I'm having a really hard time understanding what should I do.

Comment: `char` is just a single character, not a string.

Comment: What is `pueblo`?

Comment: Is the sublanguage missing `std::string`?

Comment: We could help you more if you could explain us what are your function's arguments.

Comment: Hello, I'm sorry I wasn't expecting such a quick answer. 

@Barmar   ```"pueblo"```     is a typedef I used to store different Strings,     ```"typedef char pueblo[][30];"```     I use it to print the parallel value that's stored on an enum, since I can't print from the enum.
And yes, I can use ```string.h``` in this sublanguage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`char copia` declares just a single character. To declare a string, you have to create an array.

```
    #define MAX_STRING_SIZE 30

    char copia[MAX_STRING_SIZE];

    for(int i=0; i<13;i++){
        strcpy(copia,sitios1[i]);
    }
```

Comment: Many thanks Barmar!
I was trying a similar approach in the wrong way, I was trying to directly compare two array using strcmp not realising that I would need to declare a matrix to do it, instead of going for a one dimension array that would allow me to use strcpy.

Now I have two ways to procede, one would be to compare copia with another parameter defined by the user and turn a boolean true if it was the same, or directly use strcmp to compare the input(Wich would be stored in ````char voy[1][20]```` for example) with the content inside the array.

Again, many thanks for the insight.

Answer (score 1):

`char` is just a single character in C (or C++) language, as it would be in other languages like `Java`. 
The main difference between a `char` and a `char *` is that a `char *` is a pointer to a char, meaning like a string to simplify.

Answer (score 1):

As [the other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63660225/509868) says, `char` is a single character, while `char*` is a pointer to a character (typically, the first character in a string).

String functions like [`strcmp`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/strcmp) receive strings, that is, pointers. Trying to send `char` to a function which receives `char*` is an error.

To work with single characters, use built-in operators:

- To copy - use the assignment operator: `copia = sitios1[i]`
- To compare - use the comparison operator: `voy == sitios1[i]`

Comment: The problem is that I need to compare the whole String stored inside sitios1[] with the ones I recieve from "voy" and "vengo", not just a single character, and the book I have barely adress how to do it.

Should I make a typedef char voy[15] and typedef char vengo[15] and work with that?